# How to edit an old commit and push editions to the server?

Tags: git

I have 3 commits in master branch:

- third
- second
- first

I need to get first commit (I did it using checkout command), edit it and push commit to remote repo. I've already made the following steps:

1. git checkout  (my branch is "(detached
   from ...)")
2. some editions
3. git commit --amend

But how I can push my commits to the master branch? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout master
```

And then 
`git merge 'other_branch_name'`

Answer (score 0):

just using `git push origin master`. Be sure you are at `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

use rebase :

```
git rebase first^ --interactive
```

then replace `pick` by `edit` in the editor, then save and run. You will be able to edit things, then commit by `git commit --amend`

Then, to push on your server where your **private repo** is located:

```
git push origin master -f
```

`-f` is required and means "force" : because it's usually a bad idea to rebase something published (that's why I put private repo in bold : don't do that if the repository is used by other people, or warn them first they will have to rebase or reset their local repo)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't been working on `master` branch but on detached HEAD. It is a bit dangerous since you can lose commits until there is a reference to them (branch, tag). So use:

```
git branch temp
```

Then you can put your commits to local `master`:

```
git checkout master
git merge temp
```

The temporary branch is useless anymore, so delete it:

```
git branch -d temp
```

Your commits are on local `master` now and you can push them.

(You could also make a notice of the SHA1 of the detached HEAD, skip `git branch` commands I mentioned and use the `git merge` with that SHA1 instead of a branch name. However, I find the way using branch more git-aware.)